# This JQuery animation does not work in Chrome (ok in FF & IE)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

This jQUery Animation works fine on IE9 & FF but not on Chrome...

`$(document).ready(function(){

    var width=420;

    $("#popupFlyer").animate({left:'-='+width},3000,'linear');
}`
The div is positionned via css like this :
`#popupFlyer {
z-index:100000;
position:relative;
top: 50px; 
left:100%;
width:400px;
margin:0px;
}`
The net effect should be a slide-in from right to left.
With Chrome the div start position is wrong... if I disable the animation, the div position is fine. I'm using jquery-1.4.4.min.js.
Nota: I need the z-index.
Addition of the HTML
`<body><div id="popupFlyer">My content</div> other content <body>`

Answer (score 0):

Width is undefined here. Need to see more of the code wrapped around this to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue of Chrome with jQuery 
see [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7109)